# inserting info into an external database with android

Tags: php, android, android-studio, database-connection

So i have a class register and i wanna register user information into the external database but for some reason it won't insert, can you please point out the error if there is any or tell me whats missing?

This is the php file where i have uploaded it to the web-host

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","MY_username","My_Password","My_Databas");//my_user, my_password, my_database

$BN = $_POST["BadgeNumber"];
$name = $_POST["Name"];
$EN = $_POST["ExtensionNumber"];
$PN = $_POST["PhoneNumber"];
$email = $_POST["Email"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Register (BadgeNumber, Name, ExtensionNumber, PhoneNumber, Email)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "isiis", $BN, $name, $EN, $PN, $email);  
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

This is the class where all the connection and inserting is happening and i wrote the Domain name as the SERVER ADDRESS

```
public class ServerRequests {

private static final String TAG ="ServerRequests";

ProgressDialog progressDialog;
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 1000 * 15;
public static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://92211app.netne.net/";

public ServerRequests(Context context){
    progressDialog =  new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
}

public void StoreUserDataInBackground(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){

    progressDialog.show();
    new StoreUserDataAsyncTask(user, userCallback).execute();
}

public class StoreUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    User user;
    GetUserCallback userCallback;

    public StoreUserDataAsyncTask(User user, GetUserCallback userCallback){

        this.user = user;
        this.userCallback = userCallback;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //setting the NameValuePairs
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();//stores key and value

        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BadgeNumber",user.getBadgeNumber()+""));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",user.getName()));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ExtensionNumber",user.getExtensionNumber()+""));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber",user.getPhoneNumber()+""));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email",user.getEmail()));

        Log.i(TAG,"StoreUserDataAsyncTask method BadgeNumber: "+user.getBadgeNumber()+" Name: "+user.getName());

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);//the time we want to wait until the pulse is executed (stop connection)
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);//the time we want to wait to receive anything from the server

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);//allows us to make requests to the server, we passed httpRequestParams so the client would know the connection timeout
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS + "Register.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
            Log.i(TAG,"try and catch");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        userCallback.done(null);
        Log.i(TAG,"onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

this is the interface

```
interface GetUserCallback {

public abstract void done(User returnedUser);
```

}

Here is where i call the StoreUserDataInBackground method once the button is clicked

```
 RegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //InputStream is = null;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int BN = Integer.parseInt(BadgeNumberView.getText().toString());
            String name = NameView.getText().toString();
            int EN = Integer.parseInt(ExtensionNumberView.getText().toString());
            int PN = Integer.parseInt(PhoneNumberView.getText().toString());
            String Email = EmailView.getText().toString();

                User user = new User(BN, name, EN, PN, Email);

                registerUser(user);

        }
    });   

private void registerUser(User user){

    ServerRequests serverRequests = new ServerRequests(this);
    serverRequests.StoreUserDataInBackground(user, new GetUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(User returnedUser) {

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RequestActivity.class));

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening?  Is the http connection hitting the URI?  Is the php failing to insert the data?  Are you not even getting to the HTTP connection?  Don't just dump pages of code on us, tell us what the actual problem is

Comment: @GabeSechan i know i'm sorry about that but it's only because i do not know what exactly happening because the logcat isn't showing me any errors or indicating something, so thats why i'm a bit frustrated because i don't know what the actual problem is!

Comment: Have you run it in a debugger to figure it out?

Comment: @GabeSechan i have checked the debugger and there was no problem, it executed the post and went through the try and catch with no problems

Answer (score 0):

1."Email" seems to be reserved, change it to something else.

2.Try this:

```
     dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("BadgeNumber",user.BN +""));
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name",user.name));
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ExtensionNumber",user.EN +""));
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber",user.PN +""));
    dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email",user.e_mail));

    Log.i(TAG,"StoreUserDataAsyncTask method BadgeNumber: "+user.BN +" Name: "+user.name);
```